# How to rotate specific label in ms chart?

Tags: c#, charts

I want to make a chart that axisX labels of it is hour.

One of the labels is date and I want to rotate it.

But how? The series.labelAngle rotates all labels.

Comment: I don't think you ca. Maybe you can get the effect you want by adding a TextAnnotation.

Answer (score 0):

you can confirm MsChart Example in [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-Environments-for-b01e9c61)